# Marklogic - I want do element search using java api with key-value within array section of the json document

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to search for element with key-value from array element section of the document. Lets say i have json looks like -

```
{ 
   "name":"abc", 
   "lastName":"xyz", 
   "description":"aaaaa aaaa", 
   "dob":11-10-1988,
   "workInformation":[
       {
          "address":"kolkata", 
          "workFor":"vvv Pvt Ltd"
       },
        {
          "address":"bangalore", 
          "workFor":"www Pvt Ltd"
       }
    ]
}
```

Lets say i want to search using java api inside array property **workInformation** for below mentioned key and value -

> key - workFor, value - vvv Pvt Ltd

Please let me know, how to do it.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One easy way is to use [StructuredQueryBuilder.value](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html#value(com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder.TextIndex,%20java.lang.String...)).  For example:

```
StructuredQueryBuilder sqb = new StructuredQueryBuilder();
QueryDefinition query = sqb.value(sqb.jsonProperty("workFor"), "vvv Pvt Ltd");
```

Another option is to use [QBE](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_33275).